# How can I get the value of "fcm_default_channel" for default_notification_channel_id in google Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications, firebase-in-app-messaging

Inside my android studio file for build.gradule (Modile:app), I have a value I need to replace in this settings.

```
   resValue "string", "default_notification_channel_id", "fcm_default_channel"
```

Now I am inside my firebase settings and its all confusing, I can't seem to find the value for this, Please can someone help me out.

In my firebase settings, I have this tab and values

1. General Tab

   - Project ID
   - Web API key

And in the Second Tab

2. Cloud Messaging Tab

   - Server key
   - Legacy server key
   - Sender ID
   - Web Push certificates(Key Pair)

I have this values, Please Which should be the the value for

```
"fcm_default_channel"
```

Please I need help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`fcm_default_channel` it is the value for `default_notification_channel_id` key and if you want to change it just change it from where it is exist in your android project it is not in firebase console

Comment: Okay please how do i get the value for "default_notification_channel_id" or Key for default_notification_channel_id ??? @mohammad-sommakia

Comment: BuildConfig.default_notification_channel_id

Comment: this is not in my file. i have changed all other value for other but this is the only thing giving me issues for days now.. totally confused and lost., i cant find any BuildConfig.default_notification_channel_id on the source codes. @mohammad-sommakia

Comment: if it is not in your project you can add it any where usually we add it in strings.xml file

Comment: Please are you on skype ? or should i drop mine ? i just want you to take a look.. before i go crazy @mohammad-sommakia

Comment: please see this link and fill free to upvote my answer and accept it .

Comment: https://medium.com/mindorks/code-8-add-firebase-push-notification-in-your-android-app-61a1db82e6de

Comment: This app is used for sending messages between users @mohammad-sommakia, not just notification